# Image not rendering on outlook

Tags: html, html-email, netsuite, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I am trying to create email template thru Netsuite but the image is not loading at all on outlook only.

HTML:

```html
&nbsp;
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://www.homecityinc.com/" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="https://system.na1.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=430220&amp;c=3864409&amp;h=87abba2fcc9b92415c57" style="display:block;" /></a></div>

<div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Not sure, but may be because you are using `https`

Comment: Sorry for asking the obvious but... Does Outlook prompt to download external resources and the user accepts the download?

Comment: The path of the image doesn't exist. Maybe that's why

Comment: Well, @AlonEitan, the path seems to exist, as you can see on code snippet.

Comment: @inafalcao Yes, but it's not the same path as the code in the question. Plus - the request type is `document` and not image

Answer (score -1):

This works.. Thanks for helping...

```html
<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://www.homecityinc.com/" target="_blank" title="Home City Inc"><img alt="" height="1288" src="https://system.na1.netsuite.com/core/media/media.nl?id=430220&amp;c=3864409&amp;h=87abba2fcc9b92415c57" width="899" /></a></p>
```

Comment: Could you please edit the answer and provide an explanation of what the problem was and how exactly this code addresses the issues? As it's now, it's unlikely to help anyone in the future.